# Using satellizer with ionic and express

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I have a MEAN stack application that uses satellizer for FB login.

```
$authProvider.facebook({
        clientId: '1625070294abcdef',
        scope: 'user_friends'
      });
```

There are no other custom settings here.
Once the FB authentication dialog closes, the response from FB (i.e the user data) is then sent to my express server so that I can retrieve the long term token.

The settings on my FB developer portal for website URL is:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

This is also the address at which my express server is listening.

so far so good... all works...

Now I am also creating an ionic app.. which will be using the same express backend.

In order to perform FB login, i am yet again using sateziller with ionic.

satellizer is configured in the ionic app as below:

```
var commonConfig = {
      popupOptions: {
        location: 'no',
        toolbar: 'no',
        width: window.screen.width,
        height: window.screen.height
      },
     commongConfig: {
       clientId: '1625070294abcdef',
      responseType: 'token',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000'
     }
    };
```

The issue is as follows.
In the ionic app, the FB autentication window opens. the user authenticates..BUT now isntead of closing the window..that same small window loads my Angular website (from the MEAN website I mentioned earlier)

This tells me that after receiving the token from FB authen ...it is sent to my express server. Now instead of sending a long-term token back to my ionic app.. the express server is sending the entire Angular Application.

The code to retrieve long term token on express server looks something like this :

```
var accessTokenUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';

  var params = {
    'client_id': req.body.clientId,
    'redirect_uri': req.body.redirectUri,
    'client_secret': conf.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    code: req.body.code
  };
  console.log(params);

  request.get({url: accessTokenUrl, qs: params}, function (err, response, token) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    }
    var accessToken = qs.parse(token);
 ...
 ...
retreive user details from FB using this accessToken (code hidden for sake of clarity
..
..
  res.status(200).send({
    user: user.toJSON(),
    token: token
  });

  });
```

I believe I am making some fundamental mistake here.

1. An ionic app at the end of the day is an website (as far as facebook is concerned) ?
2. I should be able to use the same express backend to authenticate and provide REST services for both my website and IONIC app ?
3. Since the website (Angular APP) is served from the same server as the express server.. it does not require a redirectUri parameter in satellizer config..(by default this is the URI at which expresss is listening) ?
4. Since the ionic app will not be served by express server..we must specify the redirect URI in the satellizer config explicitly.
   the redirect URI should be the address and port at which express is listening ?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, but you may want to look into the ionic.project file:

`{ "app_id": "", "proxies": [ { path: "/api", "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:3000" } ] }`

With that, you can set your `$authProvider` as:

`$authProvider.twitter({ url: '/api/user/twitter' });`

Then you create an Express route at '/user/twitter' -- when FB or Twitter or etc tries to redirect back to the inquirer-page, it hits your ionic.project proxy and sends it right to Express/Sails/Server and you can capture that request as a GET, process it, create a User, etc. Clearly, my experience was using Twitter, but its all normalized so I should think this will work for you.

I hope this helps!